# Random (incorrect) comma appears in JSON with very large request from Flask

Tags: python, node.js, json, flask, jsonify

Im trying to send a json from Flask to NodeJS and respond a pdf. The json contains data necessary for making receipts used by the walking collector and its basic structure looks like this:

`{"list":[{"user":"user1","month":"11/2020"},{"user":"user1","month":"12/2020"}],qid:"query_id"}`

This works well but only if the json is small enough (about 500 elements in the inner list ) if i were to pass a bit more elements (like 600/700) it will break with the following:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 98224
```

After a trip to JSONLint found out the culprit in the list:

`{ "NOMBRE": "JUAN ", "NROSOCIO": 2706, "DIRECCION": "fake_street 587 ", "RECARGO": 0, "IMPORTE": 50, "PERIODO": "12/2020", "BARCODE": "027061220201000050.0", "COBRADOR", : "1" }`

The problem its the random `,` before `:` in `COBRADOR` but i dont know why its (consistently) there

**Things i tried**

- Replacing all the data with static values
- Not putting the "COBRADOR" element in the json (the comma still apears)
- Transforming the buffer to string before parsing in Node

**Python code for generating the json**

```
        for socio in db.session.query(socios).filter(socios.COBRADOR == cobrador).all():
       
        mes =  int(mesi)
        año = int(añoi)
        for i in range(meses):

            barcode = cuponificador(str(socio.NROSOCIO),5)+cuponificador(str(mes),2)+str(año)+str(socio.COBRADOR)+cuponificador(str(importe),8)
            
            periodo = str(mes)+"/"+str(año)
            ret.append(({"NOMBRE":socio.NOMBRE,"NROSOCIO":socio.NROSOCIO,"DIRECCION":socio.DIRECCION,"RECARGO":ceil(float(recargo)),"IMPORTE":ceil(float(importe)),"PERIODO":periodo,"BARCODE":barcode,"COBRADOR":cobrador}))
            mes = mes + 1
            if (mes == 13):
                mes = 1
                año = año + 1
    
    req = requests.post("http://localhost:3000/", json= ({"list":ret,"tipo":"socios"}))
```

**NodeJs code**

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
let data = []
req.on('data', chunk => {
    data.push(chunk)
})
req.on('end', () => {
    console.log("LLego pedido")
    console.log(data.toString('utf8'))
    jason = JSON.parse(data.toString('utf8')) //here breaks
    //jason = JSON.parse(data) //also tried this
    cupones = jason.list
    tipo = jason.tipo

    make(cupones, tipo).then(function() {
      var file = fs.createReadStream('./document.pdf');
      file.on('open', function () {
        var stat = fs.statSync('./document.pdf');
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        file.pipe(res);
      });
    })
   

    })});
```

Why are those commas coming up and how do it stop it?

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with transmission?

Comment: What happens if using `json.dumps` and supplying that as text to the request call?

Comment: i get the same error using dumps

Comment: Hmm.. can the json.dumps output in Python be inspected to view if it does/does not contain the comma? It “feels” like there might be something in the middle..

Comment: @user2864740 its unlikely,  given the same request in the weird comma appears always in the same spot

Comment: I concur it’s unlikely, hence testing the hypothesis to rule it out entirely (and vindicate any encoding aspects themselves). Is there any proxy in play?

Comment: What does `repr` say? Like when you do `print(repr(ret[-1]))` after the `append`?

Comment: @user2864740 i searched the and found the problematic register but it does not have the comma, and there are no proxys

Comment: @HeapOverflow it just prints normally (cant find the problematic one this way because there are a lot of elements in the list)